# NGRX routing with Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, routes, ngrx

I'm currently doing a test project with angular ngrx and trying to use lazy loading. However, my feed toggler doesn't seem to be working properly and I don't quite understand why:
https://github.com/MiguelSchool/AngularNGRX

this is my toggle component that gives me the links to the different routes

```js
export class FeedTogglerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('tagName')tagNameProps: string | null | undefined;
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> | undefined;
  constructor(private store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.initializeValues();
  }

  private initializeValues(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store.pipe(select(isLoggedInSelector));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="feed-toggle">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills outline-active">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn$|async)">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]="['/home/feed']"
        routerLinkActive="active">
        Your Feed
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]="['/home']"
        routerLinkActive="active"
        [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        Global Feed
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="tagNameProps">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        [routerLink]="['/tags',tagNameProps]"
        routerLinkActive="active">
        #{{tagNameProps}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My routes are in app module to load the different routes

```js
const routes:Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/globalFeed/GlobalFeed.module')
      .then(module => module.GlobalFeedModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home/feed',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/your-feed/your-feed.module')
      .then(module => module.YourFeedModule)
  },
  {
    path:'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/auth/auth.module')
      .then(module => module.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path:'register',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/auth/auth.module')
      .then(module => module.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tags/:slug',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/tag-feed/tag-feed.module')
      .then(module => module.TagFeedModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
export const appRouter = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Here are the routes in the different modules:

```js
//your feed module

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: YourFeedComponent
  }
];
export const router = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

//tagfeed module
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'tags/:slug',
    component: TagFeedComponent
  }
];
export const router = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: The Github link is great, but please also include the essential parts of the code.

Comment: Please be more specific, what part doesn't seem to work properly. What happens? What do you expect to happen instead? Are there any error messages? Where do you suspect the problem might be?

Comment: To generate pages, you should use `ng g module account --module app --route account`. This way you only load the modules you really need. Eg, you don't load the `FormsModule` on the `PersonShowPage` component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how your router files should be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: YourFeedComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class YourFeedRoutingModule { }
```

I checked your github repo, you need to change every routing file to a routing module even the appRouter, and then import the RoutingModule class instead of the exported variables you are creating